# Is There An OSS Implementation Of Google AdWords

Tags: open-source, google-ads-api, pay-per-view

Is there an open source implementation of Google AdWords, or is the technology protected in some way (such as being patented)?

Edit: To clarify, I'm looking for a 3rd party implementation of an AdWords-like system (that has nothing to to with Google AdWords beyond the concept and superficial similarity).

Comment: What are you looking for? An open source way to purchase adwords to appear in search engines or an open source search engine that uses adwords?

Comment: I'm looking for an AdWords-like engine for use in sites other than Google, with the link between Google and the engine being the concept and nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what part of the system you are looking to replicate you should give [OpenX ad server](http://www.openx.org/) a try. You can install it on your own servers or use their hosted version. There are other open source ad servers but this one seems to work pretty well.

Comment: thanhks carson, I'll take a look